# Windows Slice Spark Python over data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following data:

```
id | capacity | timestamp
-----------------------------------
1  |   35     |  2020-12-01 13:28:..
2  |   47     |  2020-12-01 13:28:..
3  |   101    |  2020-12-01 13:28:..
```

And i need to calculate the mean of the capacity for each id with a window slice.
Every 2 minutes i need to obtain the mean of the capacity for each id in the last 5 minutes.
My code is the following but didnt work. I define the windows but the data is not correct.
Anyone can help me?

```
   def main():

    directory = '/Users/jose/sizes'
    
    spark_session = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master("local[2]") \
        .appName("StreamingAveragePlazasLibresV2") \
        .getOrCreate()

    logger = spark_session._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    logger.Lo

    fields = [StructField("nombre", StringType(), True),
              StructField("capacidad", IntegerType(), True),
              StructField("libres", IntegerType(), True),
              StructField("plazas_ocupadas", IntegerType(), True),
              StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True)]

    lines = spark_session \
        .readStream \
        .format("csv") \
        .option('includeTimestamp', 'true') \
        .schema(StructType(fields)) \
        .load(directory) \
        .withColumn("timestamp", current_timestamp()) \

    lines.printSchema()

    values = lines\
        .groupBy(lines.nombre,lines.capacidad,lines.timestamp) \
        .agg(functions.mean("plazas_ocupadas").alias("mean"))



    #values.printSchema()

    windowSize = 300
    slideSize  = 120

    windowDuration = '{} seconds'.format(windowSize)
    slideDuration = '{} seconds'.format(slideSize)


    windowedCounts = values.groupBy(
        window(values.timestamp, windowDuration, slideDuration),
        values.mean
    ).count().orderBy('window')
    

    windowedCounts.printSchema()


    query = values \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("complete") \
        .format("console") \
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use groupBy twice.

Without having test data to check it out, I would suggest to merge the two groupBy's (the code block between the two printSchema()-statements:

```
windowSize = 300
slideSize  = 120

windowDuration = '{} seconds'.format(windowSize)
slideDuration = '{} seconds'.format(slideSize)

windowedCounts = lines\
                   .groupBy(
                           window(values.timestamp, windowDuration, slideDuration),
                           lines.nombre,
                           lines.capacidad,
                           )\
                   .agg(functions.mean("plazas_ocupadas").alias("mean"))
```